# tsconfig to copy .sql file to dist

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I can't get this to copy my migrations folder to dist.
I have a folder in `src/graphql/DB` called `pgMem` which has a migrations folder in it with `.sql` files.

Also even though I have `package.json` there in `includes` it's not copying that either.

`src/graphql/`**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "../../dist/graphql",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./*.ts",
        "package.json",
        "/DB/pgMem/migrations/*.sql"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "/node_modules",
        "/src/test/**/*"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

When I go to dist, everything is there but my migrations folder.  Am I not going about this right?

Comment: This ussue is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835 - The typescript - compiler ignores other files than json / TS and JS - Files. You can for example use an external copy - script to solve that issue.

Comment: yea I resolved it by just doing a linux directory copy...thx

Comment: can you put your comment as the answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is described here: [github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835](http://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835) - The typescript - compiler ignores other files than json / TS and JS - Files. You can for example use an external copy - script to solve that issue.

**Alternative solution:**

An alternative is to create an additional folder in the same folder that contains your dist - folder. Let's call this folder assets. The assets - folder will be commited to the git - repository.

In the folder "assets" you can put all the static files that will be used after the deployment.

The deployment - process will then get the dist and the assets - folder (together with the other relevant files like node_modules).

When you read the files in your code it's just important that the correct path is used (../../assets/migrations/mySqlFile.sql).